# Detect the sharer used to share some content

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, share, intentfilter

In the application I'm currently working on I need to know what "ACTION_SEND sharer" (Twitter, Facebook, SMS, Email...) the user used to share a content to log it for statistic purposes. Is there anyway to do that?

I have some ideas, one of those is to modify the target Intent of those sharers to point to a receiver Intent that would receive the sharer choosen, do whatever we need with this data and then invoke a final Intent to the target sharer (Twitter, Facebook, SMS, Email...). For this final step, I suppose I need to know the share Action of each target application.

Regards

**UPDATE1**

To ilustrate, I share the method I'm currently using to share a content, customizing the Intent extras depending on the target sharer:

```
    private void shareItem(String title, String link) {
    // Standard message to send
    String msg = title + " " + link;

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent targetedShareIntent = null;

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            // Find twitter: com.twitter.android...
            if ("com.twitter.android".equals(packageName)) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
            } else if ("com.google.android.gm".equals(packageName)) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.encode(title + "\r\n" + link));
            } else if ("com.android.email".equals(packageName)) {
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.encode(title + "\n" + link));
            } else {
                // Rest of Apps
                targetedShareIntent.putExtra( android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
            }

            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), getResources().getString(R.string.share));
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

Follow indications on this link: http://goo.gl/hf8Kg

Comment: Can you pls explain what is this-R.string.share contains?

Comment: @Basim Sherif It's just a resource string that contains the dialog title (something like "Share with...").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do that?

You can display your own chooser dialog, by means of `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using queryIntentActivities() to create my own chooser dialog to customize the sharer's Intent extras (for instance, I put different extras if it's the Twitter sharer or the Email sharer), but what I need is something like a "callback" or some kind of "interception" (which is what I'm investigating right now) to know what sharer the user used. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @jihonrado: I fail to see how your approach can work. What I am suggesting is that you display **your own dialog**, where **you** are the one who populates the dialog and **you** are the one who gets control when the user taps on something in that dialog. At that point, **you** will be responsible for starting the chosen activity, in addition to recording the user's choice.

Comment: Question updated with ilustrative code. What I'm trying to do is modify this to send the Intent to a custom intermediate receiver, do something with the data, and then depending on the extra's values (for instance sharer=twitter, sharer=email...), invoke a new Intent directly to Twitter app, Email app... I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @jihonrado: "Question updated with ilustrative code" -- and, as I wrote, I fail to see how your approach can work.

Comment: I think you're right. After some investigation I reach an impasse. I just found this (http://goo.gl/hf8Kg), which is what you proposed, so I will give it a shot.